# Does .net 3.5 Application run on computers without 3.5 but with 4?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-framework-version

I am currently developing a GUI using visual studio 2008 targeting .NetFramework 3.5 I was wondering can a computer without 3.5 but with the latest version(4.0) run the application without any problem or do I still need to install .netFramework 3.5?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836704/running-net-3-5-built-mixed-mode-assemblies-in-net-4-using-app-config-requires

Answer (score 4):

You can add the [`supportedRuntime` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) to your app.config:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
     <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So adding this to the config will make the App work with .net 4? Because I compile targeting 3.5 and I was wondering how the config will affect the compatibility. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, this will allow the assembly to be loaded by the CLR v4.  But make sure you test in both environments!  Don't just go off of faith that is should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install 3.5 framework

Answer (score 1):

You need to install .NET 3.5. .NET 4.0 comes with a different CLR, and therefore cannot execute .NET 3.5 assemblies.