# Problem while uninstalling the setup

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, uninstallation

I created aplication in .net framework 3.5 & created setup project in .net framework 4.0. I installed it on the machine which is having vs2010. But while uninstalling setup , it is trowing following exception-

`Error 1001. An exception occurred while uninstalling. This exception will be ignored & the uninstall will continuw. However , the application might not be fully uninstalled after the uninstall is complete. -> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configration information.`

I added some .net 2.0 dll in the setup as well as .net 4.0 dll too. Is it creating problem? But i don't think because i'm running it on the higher version. Then how it is throwing error?

How to solve this?

thanks

Comment: Am I right that you're trying to run application build on .Net2.0 with .Net4.0 ?

Comment: Or maybe your application uses such libraries.

Comment: no. I created & build setup under .net4.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixed mode assembly in .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179028/mixed-mode-assembly-in-net-4)

Comment: @Hans Passant: I worked on the link what you have given. But it is still throwing an error.

Comment: You added just a couple of dll to the setup? why not let the setup handle the requirements? do you have any custom action on uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by adding a .config file containing the following to your project allowing mixed mode assembly

this is the "additional configration information" it wants:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```