# Mixed mode assembly error running in F# Interactive

Tags: powershell, deployment, ssis, f#, f#-interactive

I have tried to convert the following [powershell script](http://www.mattmasson.com/2012/06/publish-to-ssis-catalog-using-powershell/) for deploying a 2012 SSIS Project to an F# script.

I seem to be getting the following error when I try and run this through F# Interactive when evaluating the catalog.Create() line:

System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.Catalog.CheckDatabase(IntegrationServices store)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.Catalog.Create(Boolean execSsisStartup)
   at .$FSI_0007.main@()
Stopped due to error

I am running this using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. Could it be that F# interactive is running under 4.0 instead of the 2.0 runtime? Can this be changed somehow?

The start of the script I converted can be seen below:

```
// Variables
module Global =

    let projectFilePath = @"C:\Projects2012\Internal Reporting\SourceControl\RKN BI DataWarehouse Solution\Releases\Release 1.1.1\SSIS\SSIS Dynamics CRM Staging Load.ispac"
    let projectName = "SSIS Dynamics CRM Staging Load"
    let folderName = "RKNBI"
    let environmentName = "Dev"

// Load the IntegrationServices Assembly
#r "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc"
#r "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"
#r "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo"
#r "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo"

open System.Data
open Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
open Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices
open System.IO

printfn "Connecting to server ..."

// Create a connection to the server
let sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
let sqlConnection = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString)

// Create the Integration Services object
let integrationServices = IntegrationServices(sqlConnection)

printfn "Removing previous catalog ..."

// Drop the existing catalog if it exists
if (integrationServices.Catalogs.Count > 0) then
    integrationServices.Catalogs.["SSISDB"].Drop()
else
    ()

printfn "Creating new SSISDB Catalog ..."

// Provision a new SSIS Catalog
let catalog = Catalog(integrationServices, "SSISDB", "SUPER#secret1")
catalog.Create()
```

Comment: Look into assembly redirects in your .config file, or build whichever libraries you're depending on that are built against 2.0 from source.

Comment: try using the fusion log to figure out which version of FSharp.Core is being loaded, that will answer your question reliably. The versioning W.X.Y.Z means, F# version X.Y.Z running against .net version W. So if you see something like 4.x.y.z, it runs against .net 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179028/mixed-mode-assembly-in-net-4), you should be able to work around this by adding below inside the `<configuration>` node of `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\fsi.exe.config`

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: This seems to work! Do you know if this will have any impact on running future scripts through fsi if I just leave this config change in? I found this [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/3DVisualization-Visual-79471042/sourcecode?fileId=18993&pathId=995930383) that might just work locally rather than globally through a config change.

Comment: AFAIK this won't cause problems, though there could be some edge cases.  The runtime trick looks interesting.